# Logs are not parsing correctly in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, filebeat

My architecture is

> *Filebeat A*(remote) > Logstash A (2 pipelines) > Elasticsearch A > Kibana A
>
> *Filebeat B*(remote) > Logstash A (2 pipelines) > Elasticsearch A > Kibana A

Its for logs analysis.

say my logs format is `abc_logs-yyyy.mm.dd.log`

My `Filebeats` are pushing logs to `Logstash` (I can see in data/registry file) but `Logstash` is **NOT** **creating index** for some of the log files.

say, `abc_logs-2019.11.02.log` is there in my log location and also `Filebeat` pushed it to `Logstash`. But I **CANNOT see any index created** in `Elasticsearch`.

**Sample logs:**

```
<ip> <ip> 27 27 <ip> HTTP/1.1 - GET 8380 - GET /healthcheck/healthcheck.do HTTP/1.1 200 - [12/Nov/2019:00:33:49 +0000] - /healthcheck/healthcheck.do houston.hp.com 0 0.000 default task-245 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
<ip> <ip> 42 42 <ip> HTTP/1.1 - POST 8743 - POST /ContactServices/api/contact/create HTTP/1.1 200 - [12/Nov/2019:07:00:54 +0000] - /ContactServices/api/contact/create - 1969 1.969 default task-199 "-" "application/json" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

**logstash.conf file:**

```
input {
 beats {
                port => 5044
                host => "<host_name>"
        }
}

filter {
  grok {
        match => ["message", '%{IPV4:remoteIP}\s+%{IPV4:localIP}\s+%{INT:throughtputData:int}\s+%{INT}\s+%{IPV4}\s+%{DATA:requestProtocol}\s+%{DATA:remoteLogicalUserName}\s+%{DATA:requestMethod}\s+%{DATA:port}\s+%{DATA}\s+%{DATA}\s+/ContactServices/api/%{DATA}\s+%{DATA:requestProtocol2}\s+%{INT:requestStatusCode}\s+%{DATA:userSessionID}\s+\[%{HTTPDATE:logTimeStamp}\]\s+%{DATA:remoteUser}\s+/ContactServices/api/%{DATA:requestedURL2}\s+%{DATA:serverName}\s+%{INT:timeTakenInMilliSec:int}\s+%{NUMBER}\s+default\s+task-%{INT}\s+"%{DATA:authorization}"\s+"%{DATA}"\s+"%{DATA}"\s+"%{DATA}"\s+"%{DATA}"\s+"%{DATA}"']
 }

        if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{
                drop {}
          }

        if "_groktimeout" in [tags]{
                drop {}
          }

        date {
                match => ["logTimeStamp" ,"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        }
        mutate{
          remove_field => ["message","host","input","type","@version","prospector","beat","garbageData","offset"]
        }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<ip>:9202"]
    index => "contact-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }
}
```

**Filebeat.conf file**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /path/to/logs/*.log
  exclude_lines: ['.*healthcheck.*','.*swagger.*']

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["<serverip>:5044"]
```

> Also, one extra problem.

Even if the indexes are created, **NOT all valid logs are getting parsed**.

Like if a log file has `100 correct log` lines(as in `grok filter` pattern of
`logstash.conf` file) `only 60%-70% data` is shown as document in Elasticsearch..
around `40% data is getting dropped` .. I don't know what is the exact reason..

If I check the `unparsed logs` in `grok debugger` with the specified grok pattern, it is **parsing perfectly**.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to share your filebeat and logstash config and also a sample of your log messages so people can try to understand what you are trying to do and why it is failing.

Comment: yeah sure .. will add it ..

Comment: the grok pattern which is configured in conf file is matching only few logs and the logs which are not getting matched are throwing an error as "grokparsefailure", as per the above condition.due to that it's dropping the logs.

Comment: No @AngelH .. you misunderstood.. logs may contain 1000 log lines within which 100 correct logs are found.. the problem is within that 100, many are dropping..

Comment: I had a timeout when trying to test your pattern at http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result, perhaps it's what's happening with the missing logs?

Comment: @baudsp I think yes.I see groktimeout when examining Logstash logs.. But why? The logs are when tested with Grok Debugger, parsing perfectly. Is there anyway to increase the tmeout?

Comment: Or you could try to make it run faster, perhaps by dropping any pattern that don't set a variable, like the `%{DATA}` at the end and anchoring the regex at the start.

Comment: Also you could drop all the lines that don't contain `/ContactServices/api/`, since those will end up as parse failures, which should improve the overall performance of the pipeline.

Comment: Or you could switch to the dissect filter, which doesn't use regex, so it would be faster, but you might have to change a few things.

Comment: In filebeat itself, I did "exclude_lines" so that it filters most of the unwanted logs already.  The grok parse timeout is coming for correct logs unfortunately :(